# Multivariate Gaussian in a Sphere

Tags: integration, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, gaussian-integral

Suppose that $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a multivariate normal with a covariance given by the identity $I$ . Also, let $S_r$ be an $n$- dimensional sphere with radius $r$.  How to compute $Pr[ X\in S_r]$?

In my  attempt 
\begin{align}
Pr[ X\in S_r]=\int_{S_r}   \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2 \pi)^n n}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^T x} dx = \int_{S_r}    \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{x_i^2}{2} } dx_1dx_2...dx_n 
\end{align}

However, I am not sure how to do the above integration. Specifically, how to write limits of each integral.  I think the answer  should be roughly $1- epx(-r^2/n)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\textsf P(X\in S_r)=\frac{\int_0^r\exp\left(-\frac12x^2\right)x^{n-1}\mathrm dx}{\int_0^\infty\exp\left(-\frac12x^2\right)x^{n-1}\mathrm dx}=\frac2{2^{\frac n2}\Gamma\left(\frac n2\right)}\int_0^r\exp\left(-\frac12x^2\right)x^{n-1}\mathrm dx\;.
\end{align}

$x$ is the radial coordinate, I just couldn't call it $r$ because you'd already used that. You can perform the integration by repeatedly integrating by parts.

Comment: could you please give more details on how you changed the integral's limits?

Comment: @Boby: I didn't change the limits. I included the Jacobian for $n$-dimensional hyperspherical coordinates, which is proportional to $r^{n-1}$ (here $x^{n-1}$), integrated out the angular variables and dropped all the constants (both from normalisation and from the angular integration) since they cancel out in the fraction. All that counts is this ratio of the radial integrals.

Comment: Assuming that "sphere" actually means "ball".

Comment: @Did Yes, I meant $n$-Ball