# Why is probability of infinite sequence of independent Gaussian r.v. in a sphere equals zero for any radius?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Suppose we have a sequence of independent standard normal r.v. $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$. Also, let $S_r$ be an  $n$-dimensional ball of radius $r$ centered at zero. 
Then why does

\begin{align}
 \lim_{n \to \infty} P[ (X_i)_{i=1}^n \in  S_r]=0
\end{align} 
for any $r \ge 0$ ?

Here is an argument for the limit.  Let's calculate  $P[ (X_i)_{i=1}^n \in  S_r]$ for any finite $n$. Using result from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1731304/multivariate-gaussian-in-a-sphere) we have that 
\begin{align}
P[ (X_i)_{i=1}^n \in  S_r]= \frac{ \Gamma( \frac{n}{2})- \Gamma( \frac{n}{2},r^2) }{\Gamma( \frac{n}{2})}
\end{align}
where  $\Gamma( \frac{n}{2},r^2) $ is an incomple Gamma function. It is not difficult to check that the above expression goes to one as $n \to \infty$.

My questions:

1) From finite dimensional cases, in particular for $n=1$, we know that Gaussian is well centered around the origin. Why is thin not the case for $n \to \infty$?

2) I would like to see more intuition behind this conclusion. Is it saying that the probability that **at least one** coordinate would be outside of a sphere of any **radius** is 1.

Comment: Is $\{(X_i)_{i=1}^n\in S_r\}$ a notation for $\{X_1\in S_r\wedge\cdots\wedge X_n\in S_r\}$ here? If so then the facts that the $X_i$ are iid and that $P(X_1\in S_r)<1$ are enough for achieving the $0$ on RHS.

Comment: A.: Because $X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2\to\infty$ almost surely by the law of large numbers, say, hence $P(X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2\leqslant r^2)\to0$ for every fixed $r$. (Thus, even the condition that $P(|X_1|<r)<1$ is not needed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may become easier if we enlarge the sphere to a cube $Q_r$of side length $2r$. Then each $X_i$ individually has a positive probability $p$ of not falling into $[-r,r]$, from which 
$$P[(X_i)_{i=1}^n\in S_r]\le P[(X_i)_{i=1}^n\in Q_r]=p^n $$
and this clearly $\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(1-p)^n$, if $p$ is probability of not falling into $[-r,r]$?